# matplotlib hist2d colormap for null pixels

Tags: python, matplotlib

I found the general approach to set the null pixels to white is to use a lognorm colormap.

Is there a way to use a linear colormap but still set null pixels to white?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use '.set_under':

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

my_cmap = plt.cm.jet
my_cmap.set_under('w',1)
...
plt.hist2d( ..., cmap = my_cmap)
```

This sets all values under 1 (i.e. the lowest count) to 'w' (=white).

Comment: Very nice and simple solution.

Comment: Just in case people found it not working, add vmin=1 in the hist2d arguments.

Answer (score 11):

In new versions of matplotlib you can simply use `cmin = 1`, i.e.

```
plt.hist2d(x,y,cmin = 1)
```

will set all bins with fewer than one count to nan, i.e. nonvisible. If your background is white (default) then these bins will appear white. But they will change wil the background.